# mysql and php command sometimes doesnt post. Could it be because of my body?

Tags: php, mysql, html, post

So, I have the following PHP command to post to my db.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `db`.`tab;e` (`id`, `type`, `subtype`, `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, `title`, `body`, `price`, `googlecode`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$type', '$subType', '$image1', '$image2', '$image3', '$title', `$body`, '$price', '$googleCode', '$date');";
```

The data is being grabbed with a post. for instance, the type is

```
$type = $_POST[type];
```

etc..

However, when posting stuff, my code sometimes works and sometimes doesnt.

I think its because im using [niceEdit](http://nicedit.com/) to grab the body text and when it posts, Im worried that the ' and the " interfere with my post...

Also, the `$googlecode` is a bunch of divs with quote marks and others.

Could this be why my code works off and on?

Comment: first change `tab;e` to table

Comment: Say hello to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Are you doing any error checking after running the query as shown in the manual? I can reassure you though, it's unlikely to be because of your body: computers don't care if we're too thin, or a bit on the chubby side.

Comment: and the enclosing quotations for `\`$body\`` in the VALUES part should be single quotes, that is, `'$body'`

Comment: why not do a `print_r()` of your `$_POST` so we can see what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it sometimes failes because you don't escape the values but directly add them to the query. This way some values might break the SQL statement and the statement is vulnerable to SQL injections.

To fix this you have to [escape the values](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or even better, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). It is also strongly recommended to add some error handling so you can easier get a meaning full error message (thx Pekka).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}


$type = $_POST[type];
//etc...

$sql = "INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`id`, `type`, `subtype`, `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, `title`, `body`, `price`, `googlecode`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$type', '$subType', '$image1', '$image2', '$image3', '$title', '$body', '$price', '$googleCode', '$date');";
```